# Get text with id of textbox javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know, this is just so common. However, I am not able to get it working.

Got a php file which is included in the index.php and that contains a function printing this one out

```
echo "<input type=text id=test name=schuelername value=Name><br>
    <button style='float: left;' onclick='update();'>Suchen</button>";
```

Now I want to pass this value of the textbox. With (this is the update function)

```
alert(window.document.getElementById("test").value);
```

run by an external JS file (that works, Tested it, the only problem is the value of the textbox) isn't showing up.

Argh. Why do I define the damn ID if JS can't access it (or so...)

SOLVED: Well, I ran a document.write before it and I couldn't imagine, that like this, the rest of the javascript can't run because I just deleted everything. Thanks alot, stupid me, late!

Comment: Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/UjSJm/

Comment: You might want to actually quote your html parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. Try `alert(window.document.getElementById("test").defaultValue);`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/RzrZZ/

Make sure your PHP is `echo`ing that HTML before your Javascript tries to find it and alert the value. If the actions are reversed, `getElementById("test")` will be undefined because the node would not have been added to the DOM yet.